# How to get default value of auto property in C# using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

So I have this class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;} = 5
}
```

Using reflection how do I get `5` ?

I am trying to avoid creating an instance of MyClass. It seems un-necessary.

**Edit:** It's called "Auto-Property Initializer" value

from : http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2015/06/30/whatrsquos-new-in-c-6.0-auto-property-initializers.aspx

Comment: Class are not "Initialized" unless you create and instance of them. You are probably looking for static class and fields

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That class is actually compiled into this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int MyClass___1<Id> = 5;
    public int Id
    {
        get { return MyClass___1<Id>; }
        set { MyClass___1<Id> = value; }
    }
}
```

Which in turn is equivalent to this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int MyClass___1<Id>;

    public MyClass()
    {
        MyClass___1<Id> = 5;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return MyClass___1<Id>; }
        set { MyClass___1<Id> = value; }
    }
}
```

So other than either decompiling the constructor, or constructing an instance of the type, you can't get that value.

If you're the author of the type, the best way to do this would be to apply the `[DefaultValue(...)]` attribute to the property, which can be read through reflection. Lots of serialization libraries will use this value as well, to avoid serializing a property that has the default value.

Your class would then look like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DefaultValue(5)]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 5;
}
```

---

Having said that, here's a small [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/):

```
void Main()
{
    var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(GetType().Assembly.Location);
    var myClassType =
        (from module in assembly.Modules
         from type in module.Types
         where type.Name == "UserQuery"
         from nestedType in type.NestedTypes
         where nestedType.Name == "MyClass"
         select nestedType).FirstOrDefault();

    var ctor =
        (from method in myClassType.Methods
         where method.IsConstructor
         select method).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var instruction in ctor.Body.Instructions)
        Console.WriteLine(instruction.ToString());
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = 5;
}
```

Output:

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
IL_0002: stfld System.Int32 UserQuery/MyClass::<Id>k__BackingField
IL_0007: ldarg.0
IL_0008: call System.Void System.Object::.ctor()
IL_000d: ret
```

So it might be *feasible* **in this case**, but other types of constants, and so on, like calls to static methods, would not be easy to handle.

In short, **create the instance!**

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating the instance.

Answer (score 5):

> am trying to avoid creating an instance of MyClass. It seems un-necessary.

Actually it is not. Without the call to the constructor there will be no initialization of the variable `Id`. But what is much more important is that there will be no memory allocation without the instance so there will be no value at all that you can get.

> Using reflection how do I get 5 ?

But if you do create an instance you can get it this way:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Id").GetValue(new MyClass()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I try the create new Instance with reflection and give a type of instance class in "GetValue", it's worked!

With instance like this:

```
var myClassType = MyClass.GetType();
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType);
var latestInput = MyClass.GetType().GetProperty(input.Name).GetValue(instance);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do this in a generic fashion and thanks to Tonay's answer, I settled on the following:

```
var myClassType = typeof(T);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myClassType);
var initialValue = typeof(T).GetProperty(itemOfTypeT.PropertyInfo.Name).GetValue(instance,null);
```

Comment: The question specifically says without creating an instance of the type in question.

Comment: @Servy Thats a very pedantic response seeing as all the answers indicate that it's NECESSARY to create an instance to achieve this.

Comment: It's pedantic to tell you what the question is actually asking?  Clearly the author knows they can construct an instance to get the value.  You're not providing any useful information.  And of course other answers indicate it's *not* necessary to construct an instance, doing otherwise is just extremely difficult.

Comment: @servy he actually ended up creating an instance anyway so I don't know why you seem particularly hung up on my answer when everyone else suggested the same. I'm offering a generic version of a previous answer I found useful. How come you didn't comment on any other answer before mine when they all suggest the same thing?

Comment: Why do you think saying that your answer is just repeating what multiple other answers are saying is a point in *favor* of your answer?  Posting an answer to just repeat what other answers are already saying doesn't mean your answer is useful.  Even if those other answers were useful (which is not something I'd say) repeating them certainly isn't any more useful.

Comment: @Servy at this point it's obvious you just wish to air your grievances with this thread and have chosen my entry to do so. Others may find it useful (just as I did). To that end I see no point in continuing this "discussion". All the best

Comment: But *why* would you think it's useful?  If someone wants to know how to find the initial value of a property without constructing and object, and being told how to construct the object that they're specifically asking to avoid constructing would be useful for them, why would seeing that same answer it a second or third time be more useful than seeing it the first or second time?